# Append a range of numbers in a List in Python, as 1 Line of Code

Tags: python, list

I am looking for a list of months in Python. The result will be, not surprisingly (with syntax error)

```
months = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ..., 12]
```

To obtain it, I write a piece of Python code:

```
months = []
for x in range(1, 12):
    months.append(x)
```

Can I do this in 1 line instead?

### EDIT: GENERAL CASE

I guess many users got offended when I asked the question so I'll try to...save myself.

Let's say I want to create a dynamic list of numbers. The first and last number is dynamically selected, and stored as variables `start` and `end`. How can I generate a list of numbers, in 1 Python line, that count from `start` to `end`? Consider them being passed as GET parameters via a web request. The usual way is:

```
start = request.GET.get('start')
end = request.GET.get('end')

list_o_numbers = []
for i in range(start, end+1):
    list_o_numbers.append(i)
```

Comment: `months = list(range(1, 13))`? In Python 2 you don't need to cast into a list, range returns a list.

Comment: why is this so important that it must be on a single line, yes is the answer

Comment: You could also do `*months, = range(1, 13)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes

```
months = range(1, 13)
```

if it's python3 then:

```
months = list(range(1,13))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a list comprehension if you're feeling groovy.

```
months = [x for x in range(1,13)]
```